# Email being blocked

Tags: email, postfix

Recently my Server was infected with a trojan causing any outgoing mail to have a virus attached.  As a result Yahoo, Gmail, have all blocked any email being sent to my server or email received from my server.

How do I get removed from the block, and get my email working again with these email providers?

Answer (score 2):

For Gmail you have to fill [this form](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=msgdelivery)

As for Yahoo, you have to get in touch with the postmaster.

I found this information from these two websites, they are very informative.

[Site one](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/gmail-blacklist-removal/)

[Site two](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/how-to-remove-your-email-server-from-yahoos-blacklist/)